# Laravel apply multiple middlewares on API routes

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware

I have created a custom middleware to check if `$request->wantsJson()` then it should allow the route to call the function. The order would be
1. Check for JSON
2. Check Auth

How can I implement the middle wares in this order? I have tried the following but its not working

```
Route::group(['middleware'  =>  ['auth:api', 'json']], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix'  =>  'V1'], function () {
       Route::post('logout', 'API\V1\AuthController@logout');
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried swapping the order of the middlewares in the array?

Comment: Yes, it also doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Did you register the middleware in `App\Http\Kernel.php` route middleware?
https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    // ...
    'json' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForJson::class,
];
```

There is also an additional array for forcing the priority (order) of non-global middleware.
https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware#sorting-middleware

```php
protected $middlewarePriority = [
    // ...
    \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForJson::class,
];
```

Comment: Does this mean that json middleware will have execution priority over others?

I would like to have run the "verified" middleware and then my customized middleware.